# searching and retrieving table values using a parameter in android using php,mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

Iam developing an android app for library.And iam having a problem in searching and retrieving books based on book title or author name.Table is getting created but the table values are not getting displayed.And in the emulator it displays"Record not available".I dint get any errors in the logcat too,i get "connection sucess".And my php code also retrieving data in the localhost properly..Someone help me..

activity_screen6.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/index"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.library.Screen6" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter title/Author name"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/detail"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Search"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <TextView
               android:id="@+id/text1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"

               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_below="@+id/detail"
               android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff" />



    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="344dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/detail"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Screen6.java

```
package com.example.library;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;

public class Screen6 extends Activity
{

    ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    Button button;
    //List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

     {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen6);

             button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);
               final EditText f=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.detail);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
            public void onClick(View view)
              {
                //dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Screen6.this, "", 
                  //      "Searching...", true);
                 String result = null;
                InputStream is = null;

                try{
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:80/log/bksearch.php?&detail=detail");
                       // nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                        //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("detail",f.getText().toString().trim())); 

                        //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                        //Execute HTTP Post Request

                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                       // response=httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        is = entity.getContent();

                        Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " +e.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                //convert response to string
                try
                {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Input Reading pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        is.close();

                        result=sb.toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                       Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Input reading fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                //parse json data
                try
                {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);


                String re=jArray.getString(jArray.length()-1);


                TableLayout tv=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
                tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();




                   int flag=1;

                for(int i=-1;i<jArray.length()-1;i++)

                        {




                                TableRow tr=new TableRow(Screen6.this);

                                tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                           LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));




                                if(flag==1)
                                {

                                    TextView b6=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                                     b6.setText("S.NO");
                                     b6.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                     b6.setTextSize(15);
                                     tr.addView(b6);


                                   TextView b19=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                                     b19.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                     b19.setTextSize(15);
                                     b19.setText("ACC NO");
                                     b19.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                     tr.addView(b19);

                                   TextView b39=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                                     b39.setText("AUTHOR");
                                     b39.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                     b39.setTextSize(15);
                                     tr.addView(b39);

                                   TextView b29=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                                     b29.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                     b29.setText("TITLE");
                                     b29.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                     b29.setTextSize(15);
                                     tr.addView(b29);

                                     TextView b59=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                                     b59.setText("EDITION");
                                     b59.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                     b59.setTextSize(15);
                                     tr.addView(b59);

                                     TextView b79=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                                     b79.setText("YEAR");
                                     b79.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                     b79.setTextSize(15);
                                     tr.addView(b79);

                                     TextView b49=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                                     b49.setText("PUBLISHER");
                                     b49.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                     b49.setTextSize(15);
                                     tr.addView(b49);

                                     TextView b69=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                                     b69.setText("RS");
                                     b69.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                     b69.setTextSize(15);
                                     tr.addView(b69);

                                     TextView b89=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                                     b89.setText("ISBN");
                                     b89.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                     b89.setTextSize(15);
                                     tr.addView(b89);

                                     tv.addView(tr);

                                     final View vline = new View(Screen6.this);
                                          vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 8));
                                          vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);



                                tv.addView(vline);
                                flag=0;


                                }

                                else
                                {



                                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                                    Log.i("log_tag","S.NO: "+json_data.getInt("S.No")+
                                              ", ACC NO: "+json_data.getString("Acc No")+
                                              ", AUTHOR: "+json_data.getString("Author")
                                              +
                                              ", TITLE: "+json_data.getString("Title")
                                              +
                                              ", EDITION: "+json_data.getString("Edition")
                                              +
                                              ", YEAR: "+json_data.getString("Year")
                                              +
                                              ", PUBLISHER: "+json_data.getString("Publisher")
                                              +
                                              ", RS: "+json_data.getString("Rs")
                                              +
                                              ", ISBN: "+json_data.getString("ISBN"));




                            TextView b=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                                String stime=String.valueOf(json_data.getString("S.No"));
                                  b.setText(stime);
                                b.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b.setTextSize(15);
                                tr.addView(b);


                               TextView b1=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                                b1.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b1.setTextSize(15);
                                String stime1=json_data.getString("Acc No");
                                 b1.setText(stime1);
                                b1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                tr.addView(b1);

                              TextView b2=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                             b2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                String stime2=String.valueOf(json_data.getString("Author"));
                                b2.setText(stime2);
                                b2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b2.setTextSize(15);
                                tr.addView(b2);

                                TextView b4=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                                b4.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b4.setTextSize(15);
                                String stime4=json_data.getString("Title");
                                 b4.setText(stime4);
                                b4.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                tr.addView(b4);

                                TextView b5=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                                b5.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b5.setTextSize(15);
                                String stime5=json_data.getString("Edition");
                                 b5.setText(stime5);
                                b5.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                tr.addView(b5);

                                TextView b6=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                                b6.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b6.setTextSize(15);
                                String stime6=json_data.getString("Year");
                                 b6.setText(stime6);
                                b6.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                tr.addView(b6);

                                TextView b7=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                                b7.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b7.setTextSize(15);
                                String stime7=json_data.getString("Publisher");
                                 b7.setText(stime7);
                                b7.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                tr.addView(b7);

                                TextView b8=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                                b8.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b8.setTextSize(15);
                                String stime8=json_data.getString("Rs");
                                 b8.setText(stime8);
                                b8.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                tr.addView(b8);

                                TextView b9=new TextView(Screen6.this);
                                b9.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b9.setTextSize(15);
                                String stime9=json_data.getString("ISBN");
                                 b9.setText(stime9);
                                b9.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                tr.addView(b9);

                                  tv.addView(tr);


                        final View vline1 = new View(Screen6.this);
                      vline1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 7));
                      vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                      tv.addView(vline1);      


                                }

                       }



                }
                catch(JSONException e)
                {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }




           }
           });
     }



     }
```

bksearch.php

```
    <?php

         $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
         if (!$con)
               {
             die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }

           mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);

           $detail = $_GET['detail'];

           $i=mysql_query("select * from books where Title = '".$detail."' OR Author = '".$detail. "'",$con);

           $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($i);


           $check='';
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($i))
            {

                  $r[]=$row;
                  $check=$row['S.No'];  
           }

         if($check==NULL)
           {           
                      $r[$num_rows]="Record is not available";
                      echo json_encode($r);

             }
            else
             {
                $r[$num_rows]="success";
                 echo json_encode($r);

              }

 mysql_close($con);

    ?>
```

Comment: Add book details in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here sear number is null.
So post `f.getText().tostring()` value programmatically ..